# How to append a child div that wraps the inside content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to using pure JS (not jquery) to add a `<del>` insides the `<div>` that wraps the text 'abc'

For practice purpose, i'm not allowed to innerHTML method, inline CSS, or jquery etc. plain js.

```
<html>
<div class='todo'>abc</div>
</html>
```

my attempt.

```
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo')
const del = document.createElement('del')
todo.appendChild(del)
```

But this ended up with
`<div class='todo'>abc <del></del></div>`.
I'd like to have
`<div class='todo'><del>abc</del></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **innerText** method

```js
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo')
const del = document.createElement('del')
del.innerText = todo.innerText
todo.innerText = ""
todo.appendChild(del)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a short trick to achieve this:

**1)** Add `textContent` of `todo` to `del`'s `textContent`.

```
del.textContent = todo.textContent;
```

**2)** Remove the `textContent` of `todo`.

```
todo.textContent = "";
```

**3)** Append `del` as a child.

```
todo.appendChild(del)
```

```js
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo')
const del = document.createElement('del')
del.textContent = todo.textContent;
todo.textContent = "";
todo.appendChild(del)
```

```html
<div class='todo'>abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the content - saves blanking it

```js
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo')
const del = document.createElement('del')
del.append(todo.firstChild)
todo.appendChild(del)
```

```html
<div class='todo'>abc</div>
```

Or simpler

```js
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo')
todo.innerHTML = todo.textContent.strike()
```

```html
<div class='todo'>abc</div>
```